# sorting array manually using a reference array

Tags: javascript

```js
const order = ['b', 'c', 'a'];

const objects = [
  { name: 'a' },
  { name: 'b' },
  { name: 'c' },
];
```

Trying to figure out the most efficient way to sort the `objects` array by name using the manual `order` array.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick use of `sort` plus `indexOf`.

```js
const order = ['b', 'c', 'a'];

const objects = [
  { name: 'a' },
  { name: 'b' },
  { name: 'c' },
];

const sortedObjects = objects.sort((o1, o2) => order.indexOf(o1.name) - order.indexOf(o2.name));

console.log(sortedObjects);
```

With cached indices:

```js
const order = ['b', 'c', 'a'].reduce((acc, elt, index) => (acc[elt] = index, acc), {});

const objects = [
  { name: 'a' },
  { name: 'b' },
  { name: 'c' },
];

const sortedObjects = objects.sort((o1, o2) => order[o1.name] - order[o2.name]);

console.log(sortedObjects);
```

Comment: thanks thought this was the best way but wasn't sure if there was something more magical

Comment: Added a version with cached indices to prevent calling `indexOf` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can cache the indices using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to re-arrange the `order` object into a lookup table:

```js
const order = ['b', 'c', 'a'];

const objects = [
  { name: 'a' },
  { name: 'b' },
  { name: 'c' },
];

const lut = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(order).map(entry => entry.reverse())
);

objects.sort((a, b) => lut[a.name] - lut[b.name]);

console.log(objects);
```

Comment: nice solution, out of curiosity, what does `lut` represent? (as in why did you select that for the name of the `const`)?

Comment: @stewart715 `lut` is a standard abbreviation for "Look-Up Table"